# how to use py2exe packing python+gevent program into .exe file?

Tags: python, py2exe, gevent

I use setup.py :

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
 windows=[{"script":"flask_gevent.py"}],
 options={
    "py2exe":{
        "includes": []
    },
  }
)        



Traceback (most recent call last):
File "flask_gevent.py", line 77, in <module>
File "gevent\pywsgi.pyc", line 605, in __init__
File "gevent\server.pyc", line 48, in __init__
File "gevent\baseserver.pyc", line 55, in __init__
File "gevent\event.pyc", line 27, in __init__
File "gevent\hub.pyc", line 169, in get_hub
File "gevent\hub.pyc", line 268, in __init__
File "gevent\hub.pyc", line 198, in _import
File "gevent\hub.pyc", line 210, in _import
File "gevent\core.pyc", line 12, in <module>
File "gevent\core.pyc", line 5, in __load
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'path'
```

can anyone please help me with this problem?
in the dist directory,
i  can see some packages relavent to gevent already be included in :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved, just add "bundle_files": 1  to "options", it will work fine!